# Why do the current mobile MyMonero builds use Cordova 6.5.0?

Tags: development, mymonero, mobile

After testing Apache Cordova 7.0.0 why did MyMonero devs decide to remain with 6.5.0?

Specifically what is the distinction between how the two versions handle plugins that made 7.0.0 more problematic for MyMonero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [repo Read Me](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js),

> Note about Cordova version Apache has recently released Cordova 7.0.0.
>   It was tested, but because it now places plugins into package.json,
>   npm cannot update, as a handful of those plugins do not have
>   package.json files, and npm and yarn (based on current info) cannot
>   install them as deps. So 6.5.0 is the Cordova version that MyMonero
>   currently supports for mobile builds, and it can be selected for use
>   with [sudo] npm install -g cordova@6.5.0.

The moment this changes, or if someone patches up the install process to make it so that all the plugins which don't have package.json files can still be installed with Cordova 7, we'll remove this warning.